# Why is my reputation bouncing up and down?

Tags: support, reputation

Please find the attached screenshot

[image]

My current reputation is 895, and the reputation tab summary also confirms it. My question is why  **'905'** points is displayed next to my name for some time ???

Is this a bug ?
(or)
If my reputation was reduced from 905 to 895 why is it not recorded in reputation tab ?

my profile link https://stackoverflow.com/users/451894/upog

can someone explain the behavior ?

Comment: Now i have two SO tabs opened one shows 895 and other shows 905, and i'm sure if i refresh 905 tab it will get changed to 895

Comment: Most likely someone upvoted you and then undid that again. That won't appear in your reputation history if the time between those events is fairly short.